# how do you convert data frame column values to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert data frame column to int.

```
df['Slot'].unique()
```

displays this:

```
array(['1', '2', '3', '4', 1, 3, 5], dtype=object)
```

some values have '' around it some dont.

I tried to convert the data type to int as below:

```
df['Slot']=df['Slot'].astype('Int64')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent object to int64
```

Any ideas how to convert to int?

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: Is there a difference between 'int64' and 'Int64'? Because it works fine for me with lowercase 'int' but throws the error for uppercase 'Int'.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361121/can-cast-pandas-series-to-int64-but-not-to-int64 though that question deals with float -> int not string -> int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first convert to numeric, then cast to Int64:

```
df['Slot'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Slot']).astype('Int64')
```

After casting the type:

```
df.dtypes

Slot    Int64
dtype: object
```

As noted in comments, if you use numpy's int64 type this works from scratch:

```
df['Slot'].astype('int64')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent object to int64
```

The error you encountered is because the strings in the `'Slot'` column cannot be directly converted to integers using `astype('Int64')`. You need to handle the conversion of strings to integers explicitly.

```
df['Slot'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Slot'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
```

`pd.to_numeric()` is used to convert the values in the 'Slot' column to numeric type.
The `errors='coerce'` argument will ensure that non-convertible values, like strings, are converted to `NaN`.